# How to add VM as node to containerized selenoid hub

Tags: azure, selenoid

How to add VM as node to containerized selenoid hub. we have servers with specific configuration setup. We wanted to add these VM servers as Chrome/IE agents to Selenoid Cluster.

Could you please help us connecting the VMs as Chrome/IE agents to selenoid cluster in AKS container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenoid does not support Selenium Grid `/grid/admin` API, so connecting nodes to Selenoid is not doable. However you can use [Ggr](https://github.com/aerokube/ggr/) to load-balance requests to desired VMs.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. Also can you please provide guidance or specific example or documentation where VM is added as chrome server using ggr that will really help.